# Backbone marionette not retrieving value in global data

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

I am using backbone marionette plugin in that I am trying to retrieve the value by using get JSON method.
I am getting the value in data when I debugged it I am able to see it,
but its not coming in global data.
It shows uncaught reference error global data is not defined.
I'm providing my snippet of code below.
Since its an MVC framework I am sharing you my snippet of code alone.
It would be great if you can tell me why the error is coming.

```
/* global
    define: false,
    Backbone: false
*/

'use strict';

define([
    'marionette',
    'hbs!test/templates/layout',
    'test/views/header',
    'test/views/body'/*,
    'test/product-recommendation'*/
], function ( Marionette, Template, HeaderView, BodyView) {
    return Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        el: '.test',

        template: Template,

        regions: {
            header: '.header'
            //body:   '.body'
        },

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.model = options.model;
            var self = this,
                myData = {};


            $.getJSON("resources/scripts/apps/pages/test/product-recommendation.js",{ "globalData": myData },
               function(data) {
                    globalData = data;
                    //alert("data = " + data.self.model.toJSON());
               }


            )

        },
        

        onRender: function() {
            this.header.show(new HeaderView({ model: this.model }));
           // this.body.show(new BodyView({ model: this.model }));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You haven't properly declared your `globalData` value. The data variable returned in getJSON does return the proper values?

Comment: @WilbertvandeRidder: thanks for your reply...can you tell me how to declare globalData....yes i am able to see the values in data.

Comment: What about `var globalData = ...`? What is the purpose of that variable in this case?